# Perl script to call WCF Service with authentication?

Tags: wcf, web-services, perl, authentication

I'm using Perl script to call a WCF service which uses Custom Username and Password Validator. I just wanted to know how to pass the username and password from Perl script?

Thank you

Comment: -v would be nice: Does the WCF service provide any metadata, wsdl or something? You tagged it "web-services" so I guess it's some SOAP, JSON (hopefully not MSMQ).

Answer (score 2):

Wow, you really didn't give us a lot to go on here. A *custom* authentication script using *WCF*.

Okay, what is WCF and how does this custom authentication work? Is there an API of some sort? Does it use a SOAP Interface?

I found something about [How to Call a .NET-based Web Service Using the SOAP::Lite Perl Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995764.aspx). Will that help?

Otherwise, you'll have to give us more information.

Comment: I think WCF is the Windows Communication Foundation, and he's probably trying to host a service in IIS (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx).  And yes, more information about his current code would help, especially since TMTOWTDI

Comment: @vol7tron: Yes, I found what WCF is and that it's part of .NET. The problem is that .NET is out of most Perl hackers expertise and that Perl is out of most .NET people expertise. However, I did find something that Microsoft wrote on getting information from .NET in Perl which I think might help.